# NSURLSession - High Memory Usage

Tags: ios, swift, macos, memory, nsurlsession

In my application (an OS X app), I send approximately 5,000 URL requests in a short timespan, to retrieve JSON objects from a server. I send 50 requests simultaneously, wait for all of them to finish, and then send another batch of 50. But I'm having some memory management issues...

By the time all of the requests have completed (~2 minutes), my app has increased its memory usage by about 250MB, and this memory never gets released. I'm using `NSURLSession/dataTaskWithURL` to fetch the data, and in order to troubleshoot I've removed ALL code from the completion handler - it simply fires the request and discards the response. Here's an example:

```
func fetchData() {
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
    // Also tried .defaultSessionConfiguration()
    config.URLCache = nil
    config.HTTPCookieAcceptPolicy = .Never
    config.HTTPCookieStorage = nil
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let query = session.dataTaskWithURL(myURL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        session.invalidateAndCancel()
        // Normally call a completion handler here too
    }
    query.resume()
}
```

Note that I'm disabling all cache and cookies, as well as calling `invalidateAndCancel()` when the request has finished. I've also tried using the standard `sharedSession()`, but none of this makes any difference - the memory usage always climbs rapidly and stays high permanently.

This is a big problem, because my app needs to send these requests periodically and the memory just climbs higher with each cycle - eventually reaching several GBs of RAM. It should also be noted that my program slows to a crawl once the memory usage has reached this point.

Does anybody know why `NSURLSession` might be retaining so much memory? Profiling with Instruments doesn't reveal any memory leaks, so I'm pretty stumped here.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any more info as to why you need 5000 sessions? Sounds like you're working against iOS here, that's a crazy high number?

Comment: @Ben This is a Mac application, not an iOS app. Basically, it runs 24/7 and performs analysis on massive amounts of data. It's a lot of requests, but naturally the machine has the Internet connection to handle it. I should also mention that I've tried reusing sessions rather than creating a new one for each request, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Since you're using `NSURLSession`, make sure you're not instantiating a new one for each of those 5000 requests. Instantiated one and then reuse that. Perhaps try using `NSURLSession.sharedSession()` instead.

   I've seen modest memory consumption per session, and if you have an extraordinary number of sessions, it can add up
2. You say that you ran Instruments to look for leaks. Nowadays, you'll rarely find anything as egregious as that. But you also should look for strong reference cycles and the like like by analyzing allocations or generations between two points in time and identify *what* accounts for the 250mb, then see where it's allocated, etc.

   See WWDC videos, such as 2013's [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-410/) or 2012's [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-242/) (and ignore the fact that iOS is in the title; as many of these principles apply equally well on MacOS), which will illustrate how to diagnose such issues.

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem a bit. If I try to send multiple requests concurrently, it eats up memory very quickly. For example, I would send 50 requests simultaneously, wait for all 50 to finish, then send the next batch. This caused high memory usage that would never get freed. But sending only ONE request at a time, 5000 in a row, doesn't use much memory. The problem is, it takes much much longer to finish. Any idea why concurrent requests eat memory? I've found that creating one session (not using sharedSession) and reusing it gives the best results, like you suggested.

Comment: When running concurrent requests (and I wouldn't do more than 4 or 5 at a time, anyway), your peak memory usage should increase, but it should be freed when those requests are done. When you looked at allocations that were not freed, what did you find?

Comment: I think I need to do some more research on using Instruments, because I'm not totally sure how to interpret what I see in Allocations.  I would certainly expect memory usage to spike when requests are made, but it's strange that they're not being freed when finished.

Comment: The WWDC videos I referenced above are good, practical introductions. They include good demonstrations to using Instruments to track down issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
Config = nil
Query = nil
Session = nil
[session finishTasksAndInvalidate]
```

At end?  But personally I'd be more concerned as to why you need to make 5000 requests? Seems like bad design to me...

Comment: I gave it a try, with the exception of query, because it can't be set to nil inside its own completion handler.  But it still retained the same amount of memory.  In response to the design, I'll mention this here too for future readers: This is a Mac application that runs 24/7, collecting large amounts of data and performing different types of analysis on that data. The data comes from multiple sources, not all of which support batch fetching, so (unfortunately) 5,000 requests is totally necessary.

Comment: Did you try setting them to nil after the query.resume rather than within the block?

Comment: Yes, I tried setting them to nil after query.resume() as well - no difference.

Comment: And did that include:  [session finishTasksAndInvalidate